# expl loop in tabularx cannot create multiple cells or lines

Tags: tables, tabularx, expl3, loops

I want to break a string from a variable into multiple cell in a table. The code is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\int_new:N\textindex
\int_new:N\textindexend
\int_new:N\textcount
\NewDocumentCommand{\tablecontent}{}{
  \int_set:Nn\textindex{1}
  \int_set:Nn\textindexend{10}
  \int_set:Nn\textcount{\str_count:N \foo}
  \int_do_while:nn {\textcount>\textindex} {%
    {\str_range:Nnn \foo \textindex \textindexend} \\
    \int_set:Nn \textindex {\textindex + 10}
    \int_set:Nn \textindexend {\textindexend + 10}
  }}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}

\def \foo {aoesantoestnaoeuhtnoseuhnoauhnaosuh}

\tablecontent \\

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c}
  \hline
  \tablecontent \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

And the result is here.

[image]

The contents in the main text are broken into several lines but not in table.

Even more, if I add `&` before `{str_range:Nnn ...}` (the content out of table is removed), it will become as follows:
[image]

Nothing shows there. How can I fix the problem?

### Intended action

I want to make the table like this:

[image]

P.S I need to the cline under `foo[...]` which is different from underline and has the same style, width and height with other lines. Therefore, I want to use a table instead of others.

Comment: tabular cells are groups and that makes it quite difficult to write the correct commands to produce content going over more than one cell. It is normally much better to create the content outside the tabular.

Comment: Could you please sketch what's the intended action?

Comment: @egreg It is added at the end.

Comment: @Vonfry With nothing in the first column? Why using a tabular, then?

Comment: @egreg Only the example is nothing. In fact, there are some text. I update the intended action again.

Comment: So it seems you just need a way to split a string into chunks of a fixed length.

Comment: @egreg There are others lines before and after this box. They may shorter or longer. But all of them should have a same length underline to fill the whole box and all text should be centerred. And the box height per line is larger than the line height.

Comment: I update the indented action again to make it like the final one. The right column is like a lined letter paper and the left part has some title. I think a table is an easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick fix for your code. It is better to collect all the table body first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\textindex
\int_new:N\textindexend
\int_new:N\textcount
\NewDocumentCommand{\tablecontent}{}{
  \int_set:Nn\textindex{1}
  \int_set:Nn\textindexend{10}
  \int_set:Nn\textcount{\str_count:N \foo}
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_do_while:nn {\textcount>\textindex} {%
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\str_range:Nnn \foo \textindex \textindexend \exp_not:N \\ }
    \int_set:Nn \textindex {\textindex + 10}
    \int_set:Nn \textindexend {\textindexend + 10}
  }
  \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\def \foo {aoesantoestnaoeuhtnoseuhnoauhnaosuh}

%\tablecontent \\

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c}
  \hline
  \tablecontent
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Also a complete solution with `tblr` environment of my new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\textindex
\int_new:N\textindexend
\int_new:N\textcount
\NewDocumentCommand{\tablecontent}{}{
  \int_set:Nn\textindex{1}
  \int_set:Nn\textindexend{10}
  \int_set:Nn\textcount{\str_count:N \foo}
  \tl_clear:N \mybody
  \int_do_while:nn {\textcount>\textindex} {%
    \tl_put_right:Nx \mybody {
      \exp_not:N &
      \str_range:Nnn \foo \textindex \textindexend
      \exp_not:n { \\ \cline{2-2} }
    }
    \int_set:Nn \textindex {\textindex + 10}
    \int_set:Nn \textindexend {\textindexend + 10}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\def\foo{aoesantoestnaoeuhtnoseuhnoauhnaosuh}

\tablecontent

\begin{tblr}[expand=\mybody]{rX[c]}
  A & B \\
  \cline{2}
  content \mybody
  C & D \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]